# Python URI Online Judge (1021): o que há de errado com o meu código?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Enunciado:

> Leia um valor de ponto flutuante com duas casas decimais. Este valor
> representa um valor monetário. A seguir, calcule o menor número de
> notas e moedas possíveis no qual o valor pode ser decomposto. As notas
> consideradas são de 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2. As moedas possíveis são de
> 1, 0.50, 0.25, 0.10, 0.05 e 0.01. A seguir mostre a relação de notas
> necessárias.
>
> Entrada
>
> O arquivo de entrada contém um valor de ponto flutuante N (0 ≤ N ≤
> 1000000.00).
>
> Saída
>
> Imprima a quantidade mínima de notas e moedas necessárias para trocar
> o valor inicial, conforme exemplo fornecido.
>
> Obs: Utilize ponto (.) para separar a parte decimal.

*(https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1021)*

---

Meu código:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

valor = float(input())
cem_r = int(valor // 100)
valor %= 100
cinquenta_r = int(valor // 50)
valor %= 50
vinte_r = int(valor // 20)
valor %= 20
dez_r = int(valor // 10)
valor %= 10
cinco_r = int(valor // 5)
valor %= 5
dois_r = int(valor // 2)
valor %= 2
um_r = int(valor // 1)
valor %= 1
cinquenta_c = int(valor // 0.50)
valor %= 0.50
vintecinco_c = int(valor // 0.25)
valor %= 0.25
dez_c = int(valor // 0.10)
valor %= 0.10
cinco_c = int(valor // 0.05)
valor %= 0.05
um_c = int(valor // 0.01)
print("""NOTAS:
{} nota(s) de R$ 100.00
{} nota(s) de R$ 50.00
{} nota(s) de R$ 20.00
{} nota(s) de R$ 10.00
{} nota(s) de R$ 5.00
{} nota(s) de R$ 2.00
MOEDAS:
{} moeda(s) de R$ 1.00
{} moeda(s) de R$ 0.50
{} moeda(s) de R$ 0.25
{} moeda(s) de R$ 0.10
{} moeda(s) de R$ 0.05
{} moeda(s) de R$ 0.01""".format(cem_r, cinquenta_r, vinte_r, dez_r, cinco_r,
                                 dois_r, um_r, cinquenta_c, vintecinco_c, dez_c,
                                 cinco_c, um_c))
```

---

Realizei todos os testes disponíveis no site e, em **todos**, funcionou como esperado.

Mesmo assim continuo recebendo a mensagem "Wrong answer (100%)", o que significa que eu errei 100% da questão.

Como assim? Onde está o meu erro?

Answer (score 0):

Olá, boa tarde!

O somatório do valor das notas e moedas, ao final, dava diferença de centavos devido ao arredondamento que não está presente no seu código.

Quando você exibe duas casas decimais apenas, truncate, ele não arredonda, apenas corta:
7854.68999 nesse caso fica 7854.68

Quando usamos o arredondamento ele então manda o valor pra baixo ou pra cima dependendo da terceira casa: 
7854.68999 nesse caso fica 7854.69

Use esse valor no seu código para testar: 7854.69 quando ele mostrar a quantidade de notas e moedas, some tudo e o valor será 7854.68

Segue o seu código abaixo com uma função de arredondamento:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def arredondar(num):
    return float('%g' % (num))

valor = float(input())

cem_r = int(arredondar(valor) // 100)
valor %= 100
cinquenta_r = int(arredondar(valor) // 50)
valor %= 50
vinte_r = int(arredondar(valor) // 20)
valor %= 20
dez_r = int(arredondar(valor) // 10)
valor %= 10
cinco_r = int(arredondar(valor) // 5)
valor %= 5
dois_r = int(arredondar(valor) // 2)
valor %= 2
um_r = int(arredondar(valor) // 1)
valor %= 1
cinquenta_c = int(arredondar(valor) // 0.50)
valor %= 0.50
vintecinco_c = int(arredondar(valor) // 0.25)
valor %= 0.25
dez_c = int(arredondar(valor) // 0.10)
valor %= 0.10
cinco_c = int(arredondar(valor) // 0.05)
valor %= 0.05
um_c = int(arredondar(valor) // 0.01)

print("""NOTAS:
{} nota(s) de R$ 100.00
{} nota(s) de R$ 50.00
{} nota(s) de R$ 20.00
{} nota(s) de R$ 10.00
{} nota(s) de R$ 5.00
{} nota(s) de R$ 2.00
MOEDAS:
{} moeda(s) de R$ 1.00
{} moeda(s) de R$ 0.50
{} moeda(s) de R$ 0.25
{} moeda(s) de R$ 0.10
{} moeda(s) de R$ 0.05
{} moeda(s) de R$ 0.01""".format(cem_r, cinquenta_r, vinte_r, dez_r, cinco_r,
                                 dois_r, um_r, cinquenta_c, vintecinco_c, dez_c,
                                 cinco_c, um_c))
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está recebendo a mensagem de ***Wrong answer (100%)*** devido às falhas de arredondamento.

Para resolver esta questão de forma correta, de acordo com todas as restrições que nos é passada pela plataforma do `URI`, devemos utilizar o seguinte código:

```
valor = float(input())

notas = [100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2]
moedas = [1, 0.50, 0.25, 0.10, 0.05, 0.01]

print('NOTAS:')
for nota in notas:
    qt_notas = int(valor / nota)
    print('{} nota(s) de R$ {:.2f}'.format(qt_notas, nota))
    valor -= qt_notas * nota

print('MOEDAS:')
for moeda in moedas:
    valor = round(valor, 2)
    qt_moedas = int(valor / moeda)
    print('{} moeda(s) de R$ {:.2f}'.format(qt_moedas, moeda))
    valor -= qt_moedas * moeda
```

Observe que neste código implementei duas listas. Uma com nome de **notas**, a qual  armazena  as notas de **100, 50, 20, 10, 5 e 2** reais e, outra, com nome de **moedas** a qual armazena as moedas de **1, 0.50, 0.25, 0.10, 0.05 e 0.01** centavos.

Observe também que quando executamos o referido código, o cursor fica **piscando** no canto superior esquerdo da tela. Neste momento devemos digitar um valor real, ou seja, um valor do tipo **float()** e pressionar `enter`.

Tendo feito isso o código executará, seguidamente, os dois blocos de `for`. O primeiro bloco `for` exibirá as quantidades de notas. Neste caso, cada quantidade de notas serão o quociente entre **valor** e **nota**, convertidos em **inteiro**. O segundo `for` exibirá as quantidades de moedas. Neste caso, cada quantidade de moedas serão o quociente entre **valor** e **moeda**, convertidos em **inteiro**.

**OBSERVAÇÃO:**

O valor da variável **valor**, utilizado no cálculo da quantidade de **moedas** deve ser um **valor real arredondado com 2 casas decimais**, tal como exibido na linha...

```
valor = round(valor, 2)
```

Este artifício deve ser implementado devido ao fato das moedas inferiores a **1 real** sempre representarão **frações de 1 real**.

Só para constar, esta questão já foi **testada**, **submetida** e devidamente **aprovada** no site URI.

Comment: Outra possibilidade é multiplicar todos os valores por 100, trabalhar com inteiros e, se necessário, dividir os valores por 100 ao imprimir.